# AngularJS Model-level Helpers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-model

I have a user model that looks like:

```
{
    accessFailedCount: 0
    active: false
    created: "2014-05-09T14:39:56.867Z"
    email: "austin@austin.com"
    emailConfirmed: false
    fullName: "Austin Frtizer"
    id: "536ce8bce352b815b8791f53"
    imageId: null
    isMe: true
    lastLogin: "2014-05-09T14:39:56.867Z"
    userName: "admin"
}
```

I want to add a helper that will return the display name from my model instance... but it could be a combination of values depending on the values filled out such as:

```
fullName || email || userName
```

with other JS frameworks I've used you could 'wrap' the model results from the server with helper methods like  `myInstanceModel.displayName()`.

I know you could do this a million different ways, but I was wondering if there what the 'angular way' would be for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the million ways, create a filter:

```
app.filter('displayName', function() {
    return function(user) {

        return user.fullName || user.email || user.userName;
    }
});
```

then in your html:

```
{{user | displayName}}
```

or use it inside a controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope, $filter)
{
    var displayName = $filter('displayName')(user);
}
```

Comment: I like that ... would have never thought of use of a filter.

Comment: Do you mean inside a controller?. See my updated answer. You need to inject $filter to the controller.

Comment: I like that a lot.  Thanks!